# Display picture path to picturebox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a program with `search button`, `picturebox`, and `textbox` for file image path, i want to search invoice number and show the pictures and picture path in `textbox` but the code won't to process.

```
Private Sub search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles search.Click
    command.Connection = con
    Try
        str = "Select * from datagambar Where NoFaktur = @nofaktur"
        command = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
        command.Parameters.Add("@nofaktur", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = nofaktur.Text
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Call showimage1()
        command.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub showimage1()
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("G:\Aplikasi\Photo\Faktur Invoice")
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you encountered any errors? Also are you sure that `Image.FromFile` contains proper path?

Comment: the error is the picturebox can't show the pictures, and my pictures is saved in that folder. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Um, what's the point of calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query?  That method is specifically to execute SQL code that doesn't produce a result set.  In your case, the whole point is to get the contents of the result set, so that method is plain wrong.  You need to spend more time learning the basics of ADO.NET.  There are many places you can do that but [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) are some examples of mine that might help.

Comment: You are passing a static folder path, not a complete path to a particular file.

Comment: Also, if you have either a URL or file path of an image file, you should simply assign that to the `ImageLocation` property of the `PictureBox` and let it load the image itself.

Comment: `G:\Aplikasi\Photo\Faktur Invoice` doesn't have a file with image extension (e.g. `.jpg` or `.png`). Sounds like you need to use file name with extension (may be retrieved from DB) to properly show the image.

Comment: Also, while it doesn't actually hurt, the `Call` keyword is basically useless in almost all situations, including this one.

Comment: is your db just holding paths to pictures that are stored on your local computer?

Comment: yes, the pictures is stored in local computer like folder D @AndrewE

Comment: your search func doesnt seem to be doing anything then..., are you wanting to get the path from your db and then when calling `showimage1` it will display the selected image from your `search_click` func?